# LuaJIT 'curl_easy_getinfo' (cannot convert 'nil' to 'unsigned int')

Tags: lua, luajit

How do I pass long* in lua for curl_easy_getinfo(easy, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &eff_url); ? 
I have a pure lua script trying to perform POST & retrieve the return code using getinfo API. But when I try to do this

local resp = ffi.new("long[1]") 
local err = curlLib.curl_easy_getinfo(nacCtx.curl.handle,CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, resp)

I get "cannot convert 'nil' to 'unsigned int" error

I tried a few variations for ffi.new() to create a long*, but none worked.
Also, I went through few suggestions in other threads like
local resp = ffi.new("long[1]")   -- would create a long*
resp = tonumber(resp[0]) -- can access the value using [0] index

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Probably, `nacCtx.curl.handle` is `nil`?

Comment: No, actually I figured out the issue. the 2nd argument was 'nil', had to use "curlLib.CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE"